# generar pdf de una página html con html2pdf genera error

Tags: html, pdf

estoy intentando generar un pdf usando la libreria HTML2PDF y me lanza el siguiente error:

```
Código HTML no válido, las etiquetas no están cerradas en el orden correcto.
Estado :
Array
(
    [0] => page
    [1] => div
    [2] => div
    [3] => div
    [4] => div
)
```

El html es:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<link href="css/style_vista.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="js/jquery/ver/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="printReady">

    <div style="position: absolute; width: 595px; height: 842px; z-index: 1; left: 10px; top: 53px" id="FRONT">
    <div class="logo" id="LOGO">
        <img border="0" src="images/logob.jpg" width="197" height="68">
    </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="topright">N° <u>24</u>/2018</u></div>
    </div>  
    <div class="titulo"><span>ACTA DE RECEPCIÓN DECOMISOS LEY 20.000</span></div>

    <div class="acta"><span>
        En <b>Valdivia</b>,<b>18</b> de <b>junio</b> del <b>2018</b> siendo las <b>17:11</b> horas, la Unidad de Decomisos Ley N° 20.000, del Departamento de Asesoría Jurídica del Servicio Salud Valdivia, en conformidad al artículo 41 y 43 de la Ley N° 20.000, que sustituye la Ley N° 19.366, que sanciona el tráfico ilícito de estupefacientes y sustancias psicotrópicas, recibió el oficio N° <b>45</b> de fecha <b>18</b> de <b>Departamento Policial Sección OS-7 Valdivia</b> dirigido a <b>Fiscalía Local Valdivia</b>, que envía a la Dirección del Servicio de Salud lo siguiente: 
    </span>
    </div>          
    <div style="position: relative; width: 608px;  z-index: 5; left: 64px;top:300px;page-break-after:always;margin-bottom:5px">     
        <table id="decomisoTabla" name="decomisoTabla" class="decomisoTabla" width="600">
            <tr>
                <td width="20px" style="background-color: #bebebe;" rowspan="1" align="center"><font class="detalles2"><span><b>1</b></span></td>
                <td width="50px" style="background-color: #bebebe;"><font class="detalles2"><b>N.U.E.</b></td>
                <td>78</td>
                <td colspan="5"><span style="max-width:150px;word-wrap: break-word;"><p>
                de la buena</p>
<               </span></td>
            </tr>           
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3" style="background-color: #bebebe;"><font class="detalles2"><span><b>Tipo de Entrega:</b></span></td>
                <td colspan="2">Otros: marciano</td>        
                <td style="background-color: #bebebe;"><font class="detalles2"><span><b>Presunta Sustancia:</b></span></td>
                <td colspan="2">Cannabis Sativa</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3" style="background-color: #bebebe;"><font class="detalles2"><span><b>Peso Bruto:</b></span></td>
                <td colspan="1">8</td><td style="width:40%;"></td>
                <td height="6" style="background-color: #bebebe;"><font class="detalles2"><span><b>Peso Neto:</b></span></td>
                <td colspan="1">5</td><td style="width:40%;"></td>
            </tr>

        </table> 
        <br>    
    </div>
<br>
<br>
    <div class="paraConstancia">
        <table class="tablaFirma">  
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2" align="left" height="100px"><b>Para Constancia firman:</b></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>    
            <td><span>______________________</span></td><td><span>______________________</span></td>    
        </tr>       
             <tr>   
            <td><span><span>Marcial Vargas</span></span></td><td><span>Nelson Pardo </span></td>    
        </tr>       
        <tr>    
            <td>14083</td><td><span>15.262</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Servicio Salud </td><td><span></span></td>  
        </tr>
        </table>
    </div>              
    </div>
</div>
```

Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida.  Si hay otras opciones para generar pdf también me sirve.

Comment: Podrías adicionar el código completo de tu HTML. De esta manera podríamos encontrar una posible solución.

Comment: Lo incluí en la ultima edición.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que puedo observar tienes algunos errores en cuanto a cerrado de "tags" sobre todo cuando usas el "tag" `font`
Aquí te envió el código con las correcciones que encontré.

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<link href="css/style_vista.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="js/jquery/ver/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="printReady">

    <div style="position: absolute; width: 595px; height: 842px; z-index: 1; left: 10px; top: 53px" id="FRONT">
    <div class="logo" id="LOGO">
        <img border="0" src="images/logob.jpg" width="197" height="68">
    </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="topright">N° <u>24/2018</u>
        </div>
    </div>  
    <div class="titulo"><span>ACTA DE RECEPCIÓN DECOMISOS LEY 20.000</span></div>

    <div class="acta"><span>
        En <b>Valdivia</b>,<b>18</b> de <b>junio</b> del <b>2018</b> siendo las <b>17:11</b> horas, la Unidad de Decomisos Ley N° 20.000, del Departamento de Asesoría Jurídica del Servicio Salud Valdivia, en conformidad al artículo 41 y 43 de la Ley N° 20.000, que sustituye la Ley N° 19.366, que sanciona el tráfico ilícito de estupefacientes y sustancias psicotrópicas, recibió el oficio N° <b>45</b> de fecha <b>18</b> de <b>Departamento Policial Sección OS-7 Valdivia</b> dirigido a <b>Fiscalía Local Valdivia</b>, que envía a la Dirección del Servicio de Salud lo siguiente: 
    </span>
    </div>          
    <div style="position: relative; width: 608px;  z-index: 5; left: 64px;top:300px;page-break-after:always;margin-bottom:5px">     
        <table id="decomisoTabla" name="decomisoTabla" class="decomisoTabla" width="600">
            <tr>
                <td width="20px" style="background-color: #bebebe;" rowspan="1" align="center"><font class="detalles2"><span><b>1</b></span></font></td>
                <td width="50px" style="background-color: #bebebe;"><font class="detalles2"><b>N.U.E.</b></font></td>
                <td>78</td>
                <td colspan="5"><span style="max-width:150px;word-wrap: break-word;"><p>
                de la buena</p></span></td>
            </tr>           
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3" style="background-color: #bebebe;"><font class="detalles2"><span><b>Tipo de Entrega:</b></span></font></td>
                <td colspan="2">Otros: marciano</td>        
                <td style="background-color: #bebebe;"><font class="detalles2"><span><b>Presunta Sustancia:</b></span></font></td>
                <td colspan="2">Cannabis Sativa</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3" style="background-color: #bebebe;"><font class="detalles2"><span><b>Peso Bruto:</b></span></font></td>
                <td colspan="1">8</td><td style="width:40%;"></td>
                <td height="6" style="background-color: #bebebe;"><font class="detalles2"><span><b>Peso Neto:</b></span></font></td>
                <td colspan="1">5</td><td style="width:40%;"></td>
            </tr>

        </table> 
        <br>    
    </div>
<br>
<br>
    <div class="paraConstancia">
        <table class="tablaFirma">  
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2" align="left" height="100px"><b>Para Constancia firman:</b></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>    
            <td><span>______________________</span></td><td><span>______________________</span></td>    
        </tr>       
             <tr>   
            <td><span><span>Marcial Vargas</span></span></td><td><span>Nelson Pardo </span></td>    
        </tr>       
        <tr>    
            <td>14083</td><td><span>15.262</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Servicio Salud </td><td><span></span></td>  
        </tr>
        </table>
    </div>              
    </div>
</div>
```

Espero te sirva.

Comment: Era sólo la etiqueta font?, porque me sigue lanzando el mismo error.

Comment: Si imprimo la pagina con javascript no tengo problemas, pero lo que necesito es el pdf

Comment: no solo el font, también había un `<` y un `</u>`  que estaban de más. Te sigue dando el mismo error??

Comment: se resolvieron casi todos lo errores ahora sólo lanza el error con Array
(
    [0] => page
)

Comment: creo que lo que falta es que encierres todo en el "tag" `<page>`, que quede algo como `<html><page> Aquí el codigo </page></html>`

Comment: No es eso, por otro lado el ob_start(); lo inicio antes de la etiqueta html

Comment: me sale HTML : ...images/suppliers.png"/></a> </table> </page>...pero nunca he puesto el tag <page>

Comment: lo logré situé el al principio de la página

Comment: ¿Esta respuesta solucionó tu problema, @user2820116?  Por favor no olvides marcar la respuesta como aceptada si tu problema se solucionó. Puedes hacerlo marcando el ✓ en la parte izquierda de la respuesta (se pondrá verde, ganarás 2 puntos de reputación y podrías acceder a [nuevos privilegios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)). ¡Mira [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) si tienes alguna duda!

Answer (score 0):

He corregido tu codigo, tenias algunas etiquetade de mas y aperturas adicionales "<" ">"

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<link href="css/style_vista.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="js/jquery/ver/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="printReady">

    <div style="position: absolute; width: 595px; height: 842px; z-index: 1; left: 10px; top: 53px" id="FRONT">
    <div class="logo" id="LOGO">
        <img border="0" src="images/logob.jpg" width="197" height="68">
    </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="topright">N° <u>24</u>/2018</u></div>
    </div>  
    <div class="titulo"><span>ACTA DE RECEPCIÓN DECOMISOS LEY 20.000</span></div>

    <div class="acta"><span>
        En <b>Valdivia</b>,<b>18</b> de <b>junio</b> del <b>2018</b> siendo las <b>17:11</b> horas, la Unidad de Decomisos Ley N° 20.000, del Departamento de Asesoría Jurídica del Servicio Salud Valdivia, en conformidad al artículo 41 y 43 de la Ley N° 20.000, que sustituye la Ley N° 19.366, que sanciona el tráfico ilícito de estupefacientes y sustancias psicotrópicas, recibió el oficio N° <b>45</b> de fecha <b>18</b> de <b>Departamento Policial Sección OS-7 Valdivia</b> dirigido a <b>Fiscalía Local Valdivia</b>, que envía a la Dirección del Servicio de Salud lo siguiente: 
    </span>
    </div>          
    <div style="position: relative; width: 608px;  z-index: 5; left: 64px;top:300px;page-break-after:always;margin-bottom:5px">     
        <table id="decomisoTabla" name="decomisoTabla" class="decomisoTabla" width="600">
            <tr>
                <td width="20px" style="background-color: #bebebe;" rowspan="1" align="center"><font class="detalles2"><span><b>1</b></span></td>
                <td width="50px" style="background-color: #bebebe;"><font class="detalles2"><b>N.U.E.</b></td>
                <td>78</td>
                <td colspan="5"><span style="max-width:150px;word-wrap: break-word;"><p>
                de la buena</p>
                </span></td>
            </tr>           
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3" style="background-color: #bebebe;"><font class="detalles2"><span><b>Tipo de Entrega:</b></span></td>
                <td colspan="2">Otros: marciano</td>        
                <td style="background-color: #bebebe;"><font class="detalles2"><span><b>Presunta Sustancia:</b></span></td>
                <td colspan="2">Cannabis Sativa</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3" style="background-color: #bebebe;"><font class="detalles2"><span><b>Peso Bruto:</b></span></td>
                <td colspan="1">8</td><td style="width:40%;"></td>
                <td height="6" style="background-color: #bebebe;"><font class="detalles2"><span><b>Peso Neto:</b></span></td>
                <td colspan="1">5</td><td style="width:40%;"></td>
            </tr>

        </table> 
        <br>    
    </div>
<br>
<br>
    <div class="paraConstancia">
        <table class="tablaFirma">  
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2" align="left" height="100px"><b>Para Constancia firman:</b></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>    
            <td><span>______________________</span></td><td><span>______________________</span></td>    
        </tr>       
             <tr>   
            <td><span><span>Marcial Vargas</span></span></td><td><span>Nelson Pardo </span></td>    
        </tr>       
        <tr>    
            <td>14083</td><td><span>15.262</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Servicio Salud </td><td><span></span></td>  
        </tr>
        </table>
    </div>              
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Espero te sirva, saludos!